# How can I serialize and deserialize dynamic as IDictionary<string,object> in Json.Net

Tags: c#, json.net

I have to use older version of Json.Net (our ESB uses it) that is older than 4.5.2.

There is a memory leak for DynamicObject based classes.

I'm using Rick's Expando class https://github.com/RickStrahl/Expando

I want to serialize my Expando object as IDictionary and deserialize it as my Expando object

I tried to use CustomJsonConverter as you can see:

```
public class ExpandoConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Expando).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;

        JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        // It is easier to write readJson I will implement
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var x = (value as Expando);
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        foreach (var item in x.GetProperties(true))
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName(item.Key);

            serializer.Serialize(writer,item.Value);

            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
```

But I'm getting weird errors every time I try to implement WriteJson:

> `Token PropertyName in state Array would result in an invalid JSON object. Path '$values'.`

Is there any simple way like that (in WriteJson):

```
 var dictionary= ExpandoToDictionary(expando);
 serializer.Serialize(writer,dictionary);
```

Comment: 1) What version of Json.NET?  2) *But I'm getting weird errors every time I try to implement WriteJson* - what errors are you getting?  What did you expect to get instead?  3) *There is a memory leak for DynamicObject based classes.* - do you mean a leak in Json.NET or something else?

Comment: 1- Version is older than 4.5 2- one of them is "Token PropertyName in state Array would result in an invalid JSON object. Path '$values'."  3- Memory Leak in older version of Json.Net, The version that we used so old as you can see, I can see leak info in version history

Comment: It mus be easy to serialize object "as". I have DynamicObject and ı want to serialize it as IDictionary<string,object> It must be simple via JsonConverter but not, I think I'm missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) there may be other problems with your code, but you need to remove the inner call to `WriteEndObject()` from `WriteJson()`:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var x = (value as Expando);
    writer.WriteStartObject();
    foreach (var item in x.GetProperties(true))
    {
        writer.WritePropertyName(item.Key);

        serializer.Serialize(writer,item.Value);

        // Do not close the object here also.
    }
    writer.WriteEndObject();
}
```

Calls to `WriteStartObject()` and `WriteEndObject()` should be paired.

Comment: Only $type information is absent, but other part is working, how can I write $type?  I'm using this settings during serialization: SerializationSettings.TypeNameHanling=TypeNameHandling.All;

Comment: @ozz - you need to create an [mcve] fully showing what you are doing.  Also, the preferred format for questions on stackoverflow is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post).  In general when a converter is present it is responsible for writing ALL properties including `"$type"`.

Comment: There are no $type info in both main object and properties. There is $type but value is empty string.

Comment: ok Dbc you are right, I will accept your answer, I will try to give working example, Thanks again.

Comment: Everything is ok, thx again, (it was my fault, mySerilizationBinder's) :)

Comment: - How can we read data that we sent?
            var res=serializer.Deserialize<IDictionary<string, object>>(reader); approach gets "Unexpected token while deserializing object: EndObject. Path '$values[0]'" exception

Comment: After removing JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader); it seems working again